# How can I put this up and have text height the height of the screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site:

[link](http://www.bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

I put a picture to understand better what I want to do.

http://i61.tinypic.com/2hzpgee.png.

I have a div on the right and I want to be positioned above but do not want to be `"position: fixed"`.
Div that I want to be as height Screen height.

**This is code CSS:**

```
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      /* line 7, ../scss/_content.scss */
           #primary.content-area,
           #main-content {
                float: right;
                width: 50%;
               }
          .right{
               float:right;
               width:25%;
               height:100%; //I add this code line but not working.
              }

    }
```

If you put `"position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;"`you've seen that does not look good at all.The site is made with bootstrap, is there a class to do this?

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for height:100% to work, you need a fix height on the parent, that's why it doesn't work. And your right div isn't at top because it is in row which doesn't start at top. Maybe you should put it in page, or add a negative margin-top

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jehovazexa

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jehovazexa/edit?css,output

Comment: sidenote, ur using floats, when u downscale, and reach the breakpoint and u switch to (for example 100% width on mobile) .right is not right anymore, its equal to all other elements with a 100% width) so don't use .right or .left cause it doesn't say much:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use vertical-align:top; and float:right; in a div to achieve your goal

edit:

use

```
.right{float:right;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:100vh;
  margin-top:-40px;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

see output [here](http://jsbin.com/jehovazexa)

Comment: `.right{float:right;width:25%;vertical-align:top;}` so you say?

Comment: i wouldn't call your class right, its a reserved word call it righttext or something - you don't need 25% , maybe 10%

Comment: ok but after a class name instead work? I tried the inspector and does not work

Comment: I put 10% and width but still does not change anything

Comment: try  height :100vh;   vh is vertical height

Comment: please post what it looks like now